# persp() superimpose a specified plane on the existing surface

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I have a liner model with many varibles

```
mod<-lm(ABOTUs~SM+PH+TIN+Aridity+SOC+TSN+TSP+CTN+CTP+NTP+ANPP+BB+Pdiv,data=SFW)
```

I did a 3D plot by
`persp(mod,TSP~ANPP, scale = TRUE,theta=30, phi=30, ltheta = 50, lphi=20,col = "lightblue",expand = 0.5,shade = 0.5,ticktype = "detailed", zlab = "ABOTUs")`

now im trying to  superimpose a specified plane on the existing surface but dont know how.

here is plot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXOs6.png)